# r passing value to an internal functions not find

Tags: r

I'm still new to R..and have read about previous similar posts...I think this has something to do with the fact that r passes promises but not values, but I'm not very clear where was wrong here..

Here's a simple version of the code I want to try:

Define:

```
data<-data.frame(TYPE=as.integer(runif(20,1,3)),COL1=runif(20,1,100),COL2=runif(20,1,10))
RULEA=10
RULEB=20
```

and I'm running as the following:

```
f<-function(data,metric="A"){
  data<-ddply(data,.(TYPE),transform,SUMCOL1=sum(COL1,na.rm=TRUE),SUMCOL2=sum(COL2,na.rm=TRUE))
  data1<-f1(data=data,metric=metric)
  return(data1)
}

f1<-function(data=data,metric="A"){
  if(metric=="A"){
    RULE<-RULEA
    data$FACTOR<-data$COL1
  }else if(metric=="B"){
    RULE<-RULEB
    data$FACTOR<-data$COL1
  }
  if(nrow(data!=0)){
    x<-subset(data,FACTOR>1)
    if(nrow(x)!=0){
      x<-ddply(x,.(TYPE),mutate,sig=(max(FACTOR)>2*min(FACTOR)) & min(FACTOR) < RULE)
    }
  }

 return(x)
}
```

and if I run as following:
    f(data,metric="A")

it will give me the result:

```
> f(data,metric="A")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'RULE' not found
```

I'm not sure why it couldn't find "RULE"....?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using `data.table` which may be useful, as it avoids this issue.

note that I am explicitly copying the data.tables within each function, to make the functions behave more like a regular R function -- hence I am not really harnessing the data.table memory efficiency, but the way it evaluates `j` nicely (and it will be faster than `ddply`).

In general there will be a more  `data.table`ish way to do what you want, and this answer isn't really trying be that.

```
f<-function(DT,metric="A"){
  ## explicit copy to avoid assignment in global `DT`
  dd <- copy(DT)
  ## add sum columns to local copy
  dd[, c('SUMCOL1', 'SUMCOL2') := lapply(.SD, sum ,na.rm = TRUE),by = 'TYPE', .SDcols = c('COL1','COL2')]
  # do f1 on dd
  dd1<-f1(DT = dd,metric=metric)
  # return results
  return(dd1)
}


f1<-function(DT,metric="A"){
  ## explicit copy
  ddd <- copy(DT)
  # assign RULE (a bit simpler)
  RULE <-  switch(metric, 'A' = RULEA, 'B' = RULEB)
  # i FACTOR didn't depend on metric
  ddd[, FACTOR := COL1]
  # subset
  x <- ddd[FACTOR >1, ]

  x[, sig :=(max(FACTOR)>2*min(FACTOR)) & min(FACTOR) < RULE ,by = 'TYPE']
  return(x)
}

f(data.table(data),metric="A")
```

Comment: Thanks     @mnel ! I had been a big fan of plyr package but it might be the time for me to make a change...:)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/manipulatr/Jr7S_1GX5Yk) (old) discussion, this is actually a very challenging problem.

As that discussion notes, by the time you get to the point where you're evaluating your expression in `mutate`, `ddply` has handed off to `ldply` which has handed off to `llply`. And now `mutate` has to figure out where everything in that expression came from. Not so simple, it seems.

One (kind of horrible) work around is to change the assignment for `RULE` to use `<<-`. Hadley mentions in that discussion writing an explicit function which might be a safer option.

Comment: Thanks joran!! I just went through the old post and at least I know where the problem was! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but `RULE` will be evaluated if it is part of the `data.frame` `x`:

```
f1<-function(data=data,metric="A"){
  if(metric=="A"){
    # RULE<-RULEA
    data$RULE<-RULEA
    data$FACTOR<-data$COL1
  }else if(metric=="B"){
    # RULE<-RULEB
    data$RULE<-RULEB
    data$FACTOR<-data$COL1
  }
  if(nrow(data!=0)){
    x<-subset(data,FACTOR>1)
    if(nrow(x)!=0){
      x<-ddply(x,.(TYPE),mutate,sig=(max(FACTOR)>2*min(FACTOR)) & min(FACTOR) < RULE)
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

f(data,metric="A")
#    TYPE      COL1     COL2  SUMCOL1  SUMCOL2 RULE    FACTOR  sig
# 1     1 43.983597 9.457873 496.6858 60.05813   10 43.983597 TRUE
# 2     1 60.438590 4.196161 496.6858 60.05813   10 60.438590 TRUE
# 3     1 20.251421 6.780956 496.6858 60.05813   10 20.251421 TRUE
```

I am a fan of base, so I would probably rewrite your functions `f` and `f1` like this:

```
f<-function(data=data,metric='A'){
  b<-by(data,data$TYPE, function(x)
    data.frame(max=max(x$COL1),min=min(x$COL1),SUMCOL1=sum(x$COL1),SUMCOL2=sum(x$COL2)))
  m<-do.call(rbind,b)
  m$TYPE<-rownames(m)
  m$sig<-m$max>(2*m$min) & m$min < switch(metric,A=RULEA,B=RULEB)
  merge(data,m)[,c(names(data),'SUMCOL1','SUMCOL2','sig')]
}


f(data,metric='A')
```

Comment: Yeah, putting it into the data frame is another option, but it still feels sub-optimal (compared to the ideal of mutate just magically finding things).

Comment: Humm guess the quick change is to put the rules into data frame...wondering how much it will slow down the program on large data set, and on a real time running program...

Comment: It is very unlikely to slow it down significantly. If you need to make this fast, use `data.table`.